# how can we color the 3d mesh according to the points height in wpf (c#)?

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am  working on c# 3D wpf visual studio 2015

I had Created a mesh by using XYZ co-ordinate,
the points is nearly more than 4 million,
Based on Z-axis I need to color the entire mesh more than like a heightmap coloring.

[need to be coloured like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDjKC.png)

this is for the  adding the position to the points:

```
MeshGeometry3D cube = new MeshGeometry3D();
cube.Positions.Add(new Point3D(X[i], Y[i], Z[i]));
```

for creating the indices:

```
cube.TriangleIndices.Add(m);
cube.TriangleIndices.Add(m + 1);
cube.TriangleIndices.Add((m + 1) + line);
cube.TriangleIndices.Add((m + 1) + line);
cube.TriangleIndices.Add((m + 2) + line);
cube.TriangleIndices.Add(m);
```

```
myHorizontalGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.LimeGreen, 5));
mGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(cube, new DiffuseMaterial(myHorizontalGradient));
group.Children.Add(mGeometry);
```

here instead of light blue based on height the color should be iterated till the end.

```
    byte rr = 0;
    for (int pp = 0; pp < l; pp++) //l is the number of points
    {
        Color cc = Color.FromArgb(rr, 0, 0, 0);
        myHorizontalGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(cc, 5));
        mGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(cube, new DiffuseMaterial(myHorizontalGradient));
        mGeometry.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();
        group.Children.Add(mGeometry);
        rr++;
        if (rr > 255)
        {
            rr = 0;
        }
    }
```

this is how is used to iterate the color now i just tried for red colour only but it doesn't worked

Comment: Have you played around with `GeometryModel3D`'s `Material` and `BackMaterial` properties? Also how are you using `myHorizontalGradient`? I see it being defined but not being consumed.

Comment: No I'm still a newbie to wpf .But I had tried some other methods but it doesn't worked out,can you please give any reference for which i'm looking for.

Comment: I just did. Show us how you are using the gradient?

Comment: LinearGradientBrush myHorizontalGradient = new LinearGradientBrush(); byte rr = 0;for (int pp = 0; pp < l; pp++){
Color cc = Color.FromArgb(rr, 0, 0, 0);
myHorizontalGradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(cc, 5));
                                mGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(cube, new DiffuseMaterial(myHorizontalGradient));
mGeometry.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();
group.Children.Add(mGeometry);
rr++;
if (rr > 255)
{
rr = 0;
}
}

Comment: I want to help you, in order to I'll need a piece of code that I can execute on my machine and play around with. There are too many open gaps in your code for me to run it. Can you create/edit an example that I could run - xaml & C#? Doesn't have to be your entire project, just a minimal example.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23332/WPF-3D-Primer I had Used this as my reference.for xaml

Comment: Can't find the time to take a look. Sorry.

Comment: Atleast can you please say how we can do that? Because which ever method I used doesn't get me the proper expected output.help me out of this!!

Comment: You should use a 1D texture (from 0 to 255 for example in width) and map your Z coordinate on the UV coordinate as a ratio from size.min to size.max mapped to [0;255].
Then you'll have a gradient on your mesh based on your 1D texture 
- Pretty straight forward to implement
- you could change the texture at run time to display different gradients